# How to build a full text semantic search engine using firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

Does someone have any recommendations for building a semantic search full-text engine for Flutter whilst storing the documents in Firestore, i have heard about Typesense and Elastic Search. I just want to build a function that can search for the most related answers semantically.

Answer (score 1):

As the official documentation regarding [full-text search in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) states, there are only three options available by the time I'm answering this question, which are [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/app-search/), [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/), and [Typesense](https://typesense.org/).

If you want, you can simplify the process by using the corresponding Firebase Extensions:

- [Search with Elastic App Search](https://extensions.dev/extensions/elastic/firestore-elastic-app-search)
- [Search Firestore with Algolia](https://extensions.dev/extensions/algolia/firestore-algolia-search)
- [Search Firestore with Typesense](https://extensions.dev/extensions/typesense/firestore-typesense-search)

Comment: Hey Tomas. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?